# removing first 8 bytes using dd is very slow

Tags: linux, bash, dd

I'm trying to remeove the first 8 bytes from binary file using the command:

```
dd if=new.pdf of=new2.pdf ibs=1 skip=8
```

but it's taking too long.

Is there a way to remove the first 8 bytes, in a faster way ?

Comment: This question on the Unix&Linux Stack Exchange might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/best-way-to-remove-bytes-from-the-start-of-a-file There are a few other related questions there, as well.

Comment: `but it's taking too long.` `ibs=1` - you are reading one character at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ibs=1` is requesting `dd` to read one single byte at a time. It's going to be slow - for each byte, there is a context switch to the kernel.

I would:

```
tail -c+9 new.pdf > new2.pdf
```

I think you could use `dd`, choose the best block size for your specific environment, and... skip the bytes:

```
dd if=new.pdf of=new2.pdf bs=4M iflag=skip_bytes skip=8
```